# Automate Build from Visual Studio Online using MSBuild & Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, azure-devops

I want to build the code using MSbuild Script in Jenkins. My code repository is on Visual Studio Online. The below script does not copy anything in the output folder on my local machine. Whereas if I am using the same script on my local machine it works fine. Below is the script I am using for my build:

```
   <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <BuildArtifactsDir Include="D:\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace\BuildArtifacts\"/>
    <TeamFoundationServerUrl Include="https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/XXX-XXX/"/>
    <SolutionFile Include="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)*.sln"/>
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
    <BuildPlatForm Condition="'$(BuildPlatForm)'=='' ">Any CPU</BuildPlatForm>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Init">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFile)" Targets="Rebuild"
             Properties="OutDir=%(BuildArtifactsDir.FullPath);Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(BuildPlatform)"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="Init">
    <MakeDir Directories="@(BuildArtifactsDir)"/>
</Target>
```

My Environment:

Jenkins: On my local host.
MSBuild Plugin in Jenkins.
Visual Studio Online for Code repository.

Comment: How do you authenticate to VSO? Running MSBuild interactively, the credential is taken from Credential Manager store, but Jenkins is running as a service, probably using LocalSystem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the solution from VSO/TFS via msbuild directly.

To connect to VSO/TFS server from Jenkins, you can install TFS Plug-in in your Jenkins server via "Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available -> Team Foundation Server Plug-in". And then configure your project like following:
[image]
The plug-in will get the latest solution from your VSO/TFS server and copy it to your Jenkins server, you can then update your msbuild script accordingly.

Please note that you need to use "Alternate authentication credentials" to log in VSO/TFS server with this plug-in. To enable this feature, sign in your VSO/TFS account, enable it under "My Profile/Security/Alternate authentication credentials".

Comment: I did the same steps earlier and able to get the latest code from the VSO but i would like to get the build(only .dll, .cshtml, .css, .html, .js file etc except .CS file)  only from VSP using MSBuild. Can i convert into build using MSBuild. Please suggest me.

Comment: I would like to download the artifacts from VSO using MSBuild in Jenkins.

Comment: MSBuild can only build the solution you specified and publish the artifacts to the specified location. It cannot achieve the actions like connect to TFS, copy artifacts.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i publish the artifacts to the specified location using? Since MSBuild just download the solution to Workspace in Jenkins from VSO. Is there a way the solution can be build and publish artifacts using MSBuild?

Comment: MSBuild don't download the solution to Workspace. The solution is downloaded by TFS plugin. MSBuild only build the exist solution in the workspace and place the artifacts to the location you specified. I'm a little confused about your question. Do you mean you'd like to build your solution in VSO and then download the artifact to Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, exactly same, I would like to build the solution in VSO and then want to download the Artifacts.

Comment: MSBuild cannot do this. If you indeed want to do this, I suggest you set "Artifacts Type" to "File Share" in your VSO build definition and publish the artifacts to an UNC share path. And in Jenkins, add an "Execute Windows batch command" to copy the artifacts from UNC share path to Jenkins workspace.

Comment: Thanks for response. I got your point but the thing is Jenkins is on local host so how can i give the UNC path in file share.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to deploy the artifacts _Publishwebsite on FTP from VSO?

Comment: You could refer to the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547518/how-to-deploy-artifacts-on-ftp-from-visual-studio-online