# How to deploy Artifacts on FTP from Visual Studio Online?

Tags: ftp, azure-devops

I have set up automate build on Visual Studio Online and able to get the artifacts under builds. Now i want to deploy the artifacts on FTP. Since my website is hosted on GoDaddy and they provided me FTP account.Can anyone please help me out to set up this.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the standard build step called "cURL Upload Files", which can be found in Utility section. It claims to support many protocols, including FTP. The following screenshot might give you an idea of how to configure it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have one doubt that .zip file automatic will be unzip after deploy on FTP?

Comment: Most likely it won't. Zip is just an example. You can specify any file types, hover over the information icon, it contains a hint.

Comment: I received this error while cURL task start :Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\cURLUploader\1.0.0\cURLUploader.ps1C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl.exe --stderr -  -u "xxxxxx":"xxxxxxxx" -T C:/a/1/a ftp://208.xx.xx.xxx/qacurl: Can't open 'C:/a/1/a'!curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more informationUnexpected exit code 26 returned from tool curl.exe

Comment: @ManojSharma, it looks like incorrectly formatted cURL command line. Verify that it works without TFS build involved. By the way, you mentioned you're executing PowerShell script. This isn't required - the build step I described above can make cURL calls directly, without being wrapped in PowerShell script.

Comment: Hi, I did not mentioned the powershell script its automatically run in VSO. Can you please explain more about cURL.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the information from the build log? It might be some escaping stuff...

Comment: This is the log error: cURL task start :Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\cURLUploa‌​der\1.0.0\cURLUploader.ps1C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl.exe --stderr - -u "xxxxxx":"xxxxxxxx" -T C:/a/1/a 208.xx.xx.xxx/qacurl: Can't open 'C:/a/1/a'!curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more informationUnexpected exit code 26 returned from tool curl.exe

Comment: Your code build folder or artifact is either cleaned or deleted before running cURL.

Answer (score 1):

**1) FTP :**

Connecting to GoDaddy using FTP is a big issue. I suspect that this is mainly due to the expired TLS certificate. I dropped FTP setup idea after failing to connect numerous time and also have read few articles that FTP protocol is not that reliable, error prone and SSH was a suggested alternative.

**2) cURL**

Using cURL based uploader might work. But for a huge project with too many files will result in ENAME Too Long error (i.e., list of files willl be created as a lengthy string and set as an argument which results in the error).

**3) Web Deploy:**

Since web deploy service seems to work from visual studio IDE from the local/development machine to Godaddy servers, we can be sure that it will work from Visual Studio based build template on VSTS hosted environment too.

Well this was the only method that worked for me.

You can check out the steps and configuration detailed in the article - [HOW TO SETUP VSTS CONTINUOUS DEPLOYMENT FOR GODADDY](https://davidsekar.com/source-control/how-to-setup-vsts-continuous-deployment-for-godaddy)